# Server-Side Auth Flow with React Router

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router, url-routing, isomorphic-javascript

I was wondering how to exactly implement authentication flow with React Router if my app is rendering server-side?

#### The scenario:

When the user first arrives at the app, we invoke an `onEnter` router method in order to check if any current user is present (`localStorage`), if they are we will redirect them to their dashboard, otherwise we redirect them to the landing page.

Therefore when my app hits my protected routes `onEnter`, here's ideally what should happen:

```
onEnter: () => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('authToken')) {
        // Authenticate and redirect user to intended path
    } else {
        // Redirect the user to the login page
    }
}
```

The problem here is that because we're rendering server-side, we don't have access to things such as `localStorage`. Can anyone suggest a way to overcome this, or a better way to handle server-side auth with React Router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html), e.g:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes, Children } from 'react'

class Provider extends Component {

    static childContextTypes = {
        isAuthed: PropTypes.bool
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.initialData = isClient ? window.__initialData__ : props.initialData;
    }

    getChildContext() {
        return {
            isAuthed: this.initialData.isAuthed
        };
    }

    render() {
        let { children } = this.props;
        return Children.only(children);
    }
}
```

And wrap:

```
// The server creates this object:
const initialData = {
    isAuthed: true
};

if (IS_CLIENT) {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider>
            <Router history={createHistory()}>{Routes}</Router>
        </Provider>,
        document.getElementById('app')
    );
}

if (IS_SERVER) {
    // Using renderToStaticMarkup/renderToString etc on:
    <Provider initialData={initialData}> 
        <RoutingContext {...renderProps} />
    </Provider>
}
```

You can then access it on the server or client from any component:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'

class SomeComponent extends Component {

    static contextTypes = {
        isAuthed: PropTypes.bool
    }

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        console.log(context.isAuthed); // this.context outside ctor
    }
}
```

Simple client check something like `typeof document !== 'undefined'`

Comment: Great solution! Gonna try it tonight :) Thanks!

Comment: this doesn't convince me. On the server-side, a request was made, and the Authorization header may include (or not) the JWT that we need to assure the user is authenticated. How can I have access to the request headers from within the route?